# Value for frame.size.height is always the same regardless of height of view

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have two views on a super view. View B is beneath View A:

```
VIEW A
fixed top space to top layout guide 
fixed height

VIEW B
fixed top space to View A
fixed bottom space to bottom layout guide
```

The idea is for View A height + View B height to fill the screen vertically. This is working well. If I change the constant of View A's height constraint the views resize as I expect. View B's height grows or shrinks to take up the rest of the screen.

However, the values for both views' height does not change and is always 568.0. I am looking at `a view's frame.size.height` for this.  The values are always 568.0 (I am testing on an iPhone 6) regardless of the actual size of the view.

I have this:

```
heightConstraintViewA.constant = 300.0
println( "\(viewA.frame.size.height)" )  // this is always 568.0
```

Comment: Is this causing a problem?

Comment: You have that code _when_? _Where_? If you check it before layout, then by definition layout hasn't happened yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that constraints and layout are two different things. A constraint is just an instruction. It is not *obeyed* until layout time, which is much later.

So, you can set a view's height constraint, but nothing else happens *at that moment*. There is no point checking the view's height in the next line after you change the constraint, because *nothing has happened yet*.

Later, layout happens, and the constraint is obeyed - and, if that's what the constraints mean, the height actually changes.

Comment: That was it. Heavy sigh. I was checking before layout had occurred. Once I can accept your answer I'll post simple before/after values. Many many thanks.